# How to mount Amazon S3 within PHP project

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is what I tried to do. I mounted an S3 Bucket inside my PHP environment as a folder. I then tried to write files into the folder so that they will be stored on S3 instead of my local. I got it to mount and I created files in the environment and those worked. But when I PHP tries to write into the directory, it says:

```
Only 0 of 437 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in [directory]
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you using to mount s3?  Is it s3fs?  If so, it could be a permissions issue.  Is your php script running under the same user that you used to create the files?

Comment: I'm using riofs. I have the allow other option and the mount works normally. It just doesn't work in PHP